# Bootstrap 3 - how to hide input-group-btn on a specific device

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wish to hide an input-group-btn when viewed on extra-small devices.  What is the appropriate way to achieve this?

I've tried the following:

```
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <div class="input-group-btn hidden-xs">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /btn-group --> 
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
```

But it messes up the rendering of the input-group http://bootply.com/81206

Without 'hidden-xs':

[image]

With 'hidden-xs':

[image]

Comment: How is it messed up? Seems to look ok on the Bootply.

Comment: It's messed up because the input should be 100% of the width and the input-group-btn appears on a new line when visible.  Remove the 'hidden-xs' class and you will see how it *should* look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the use of [responsive utility classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes) on table-* elements is not supported in Bootstrap 3:

> Responsive utilities are currently only available for block and table toggling. Use with inline and table elements is currently not supported.

The `.hidden-*` classes toggle an element between `display: block;` and `display: none` which is breaking your layout since `.input-group` and `.input-btn-group` use table display values. I'm unsure of a workaround for this.

Comment: Aargh! So that would mean having to duplicate my input-goup to achieve what I want :(

Comment: I'm afraid so. I was unable to find an alternative workaround :(

Comment: I managed to work around it - see the update to my question :)

Comment: @gpcola You could have added the solution edit as an answer. It would make it clearer and allow it to get voted/commented on independent of the question.

Answer (score 2):

@Focus is right, this isn't possible using [responsive utility classes][3], but I managed to work around it http://bootply.com/81230

CSS

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .hidebtn-xs, .hidebtn-xs input {
        display: block !important;
    }
    .hidebtn-xs .input-group-btn {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="input-group hidebtn-xs">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /btn-group --> 
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
```